# Slimdx texture from webcam capture using Directshow.NET, mismatch in image formats?

Tags: textures, directshow.net, slimdx

This is my first question on stackoverflow.
Im using Directshow.NET to capture a webcam and then render it using SlimDX.
Though I cant get the texture to render correctly.

This is what I get if I copy the data from the webcam to a bitmap and set it to a picturebox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qxw08b89613u7gl/Bitmap.PNG
(Seems like I cant post pictures when its my first post)

Though if I copy the data to a texture and render it I get:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvoj2qzfv80q84x/d3dTexture.PNG

This is my camera capture class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DirectShowLib;
using SlimDX;
using SlimDX.Direct3D9;

namespace SlimDXTest
{
    public delegate void FrameCompleteEventHandler(ref Texture texture);

    class Camera : ISampleGrabberCB, IDisposable
    {
        public event FrameCompleteEventHandler FrameComplete;

        private object lockObject = new object();
        private IMediaControl mediaControl = null;
        private IMediaEvent mediaEvent = null;
        private IGraphBuilder pGraph = null;
        private byte[] frameData = new byte[1280 * 720 * 4];
        private Device d3dDevice;
        public Texture texture;
        public System.Drawing.Bitmap currentBitmap = null;
        private Test bitmapWindow;

        public Camera(DsDevice device, Device d3dDevice)
        {
            bitmapWindow = new Test();
            bitmapWindow.Show();
            this.d3dDevice = d3dDevice;

            texture = new Texture(d3dDevice, 1280, 720, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);


            try
            {
                BuildGraph(device);
            }
            catch
            {
                Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void BuildGraph(DirectShowLib.DsDevice dsDevice)
        {
            int hr = 0;
            pGraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;

            //graph builder
            ICaptureGraphBuilder2 pBuilder = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();

            try
            {
                hr = pBuilder.SetFiltergraph(pGraph);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Add camera
                IBaseFilter camera;
                //hr = pGraph.FindFilterByName(dsDevice.Name, out camera);
                hr = ((IFilterGraph2)pGraph).AddSourceFilterForMoniker(dsDevice.Mon, null, dsDevice.Name, out camera);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                hr = pGraph.AddFilter(camera, "camera");
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Set format for camera
                AMMediaType pmt = new AMMediaType();
                pmt.majorType = MediaType.Video;
                pmt.subType = MediaSubType.MJPG;
                pmt.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
                pmt.fixedSizeSamples = true;
                pmt.formatSize = 88;
                pmt.sampleSize = 2764800;
                pmt.temporalCompression = false;
                VideoInfoHeader format = new VideoInfoHeader();
                format.SrcRect = new DsRect();
                format.TargetRect = new DsRect();
                format.BitRate = 663552000;
                format.AvgTimePerFrame = 333333;
                format.BmiHeader = new BitmapInfoHeader();
                format.BmiHeader.Size = 40;
                format.BmiHeader.Width = 1280;
                format.BmiHeader.Height = 720;
                format.BmiHeader.Planes = 1;
                format.BmiHeader.BitCount = 24;
                format.BmiHeader.Compression = 1196444237;
                format.BmiHeader.ImageSize = 2764800;
                pmt.formatPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(format));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(format, pmt.formatPtr, false);
                hr = ((IAMStreamConfig)DsFindPin.ByCategory(camera, PinCategory.Capture, 0)).SetFormat(pmt);
                //hr = ((IAMStreamConfig)GetPin(pUSB20Camera, "Capture")).SetFormat(pmt);
                DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(pmt);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                //add MJPG Decompressor
                IBaseFilter pMJPGDecompressor = (IBaseFilter)new MjpegDec();
                hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pMJPGDecompressor, "MJPG Decompressor");
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                //add color space converter
                IBaseFilter pColorSpaceConverter = (IBaseFilter)new Colour();
                hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pColorSpaceConverter, "Color space converter");
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Connect camera and MJPEG Decomp
                //hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pUSB20Camera, "Capture"), GetPin(pMJPGDecompressor, "XForm In"), null);
                hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(DsFindPin.ByCategory(camera, PinCategory.Capture, 0), DsFindPin.ByName(pMJPGDecompressor, "XForm In"), null);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Connect MJPG Decomp and color space converter
                hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(DsFindPin.ByName(pMJPGDecompressor, "XForm Out"), DsFindPin.ByName(pColorSpaceConverter, "Input"), null);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                //add SampleGrabber
                //IBaseFilter pSampleGrabber = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_SampleGrabber));
                //hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pSampleGrabber, "SampleGrabber");
                IBaseFilter sampleGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as IBaseFilter;
                hr = pGraph.AddFilter(sampleGrabber, "Sample grabber");
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                // Configure the samplegrabber
                AMMediaType pSampleGrabber_pmt = new AMMediaType();
                pSampleGrabber_pmt.majorType = MediaType.Video;
                pSampleGrabber_pmt.subType = MediaSubType.ARGB32;
                pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
                pSampleGrabber_pmt.fixedSizeSamples = true;
                pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatSize = 88;
                pSampleGrabber_pmt.sampleSize = 3686400;
                pSampleGrabber_pmt.temporalCompression = false;
                VideoInfoHeader pSampleGrabber_format = new VideoInfoHeader();
                pSampleGrabber_format.SrcRect = new DsRect();
                pSampleGrabber_format.TargetRect = new DsRect();
                pSampleGrabber_format.BitRate = 884736885;
                pSampleGrabber_format.AvgTimePerFrame = 333333;
                pSampleGrabber_format.BmiHeader = new BitmapInfoHeader();
                pSampleGrabber_format.BmiHeader.Size = 40;
                pSampleGrabber_format.BmiHeader.Width = 1280;
                pSampleGrabber_format.BmiHeader.Height = 720;
                pSampleGrabber_format.BmiHeader.Planes = 1;
                pSampleGrabber_format.BmiHeader.BitCount = 32;
                //pSampleGrabber_format.BmiHeader.Compression = 1196444237;
                pSampleGrabber_format.BmiHeader.ImageSize = 3686400;
                pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(pSampleGrabber_format));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(pSampleGrabber_format, pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatPtr, false);
                hr = ((ISampleGrabber)sampleGrabber).SetMediaType(pSampleGrabber_pmt);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);



                //connect MJPG dec and SampleGrabber
                //hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pMJPGDecompressor, "XForm Out"), GetPin(pSampleGrabber, "Input"), null);
                hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(DsFindPin.ByName(pColorSpaceConverter, "XForm Out"), DsFindPin.ByName(sampleGrabber, "Input"), null);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                //set callback
                hr = ((ISampleGrabber)sampleGrabber).SetCallback(this, 1);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean this mess up!
            }
        }

        public void StartCapture()
        {
            IMediaControl mediaControl = (IMediaControl)pGraph;
            IMediaEvent mediaEvent = (IMediaEvent)pGraph;
            int hr = mediaControl.Run();
        }

        public int BufferCB(double SampleTime, IntPtr pBuffer, int BufferLen)
        {

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(pBuffer, frameData, 0, BufferLen);

                var data = texture.LockRectangle(0, LockFlags.None);
                data.Data.Write(frameData, 0, BufferLen);
                texture.UnlockRectangle(0);
                /*
                Surface privateSurface = texture.GetSurfaceLevel(0);
                var graphicsStream = privateSurface.LockRectangle(LockFlags.None);
                graphicsStream.Data.WriteRange(pBuffer, BufferLen);
                privateSurface.UnlockRectangle();
                */
                currentBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(1280, 720, 1280 * 4, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, pBuffer);
                (bitmapWindow.getPixBox()).Image = currentBitmap;
                FrameComplete(ref texture);
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public int SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample pSample)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out what the problem is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.